# vb.net system beep sound on XP

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, beep

Is it possible to have a vb.net program sound the PC's internal speaker? you know the one that produces C's `\a` BELL
I have tried `beep()`, but this only produces the error sound on the sound card.
I have also tried

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint:="Beep", SetLastError:=True, _
CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, _
CallingConvention:=Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Shared Function _
   aBeep(ByVal dwFreq As Integer, ByVal dwDuration As Integer) _
     As Boolean
End Function
```

With no joy apparently its only good on Vista and above.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You know that not all computers even *have* a built-in hardware speaker like the one you describe, right? So this program will likely not perform as expected in a large number of cases, particularly with the cheap machines found in corporate environments.

Comment: Also, is this 64-bit Windows XP? Because last I remember (it's been a long time since I used XP), the [`Beep` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277.aspx) caused a beep to be emitted from the internal system speaker, like you describe. This is contrast to the `MessageBeep` function, which would beep from the sound card if attached. 64-bit versions of XP and Windows Vista were the first to break this behavior.

Comment: Damn it I am on a 64-bit version... guess my user will just have to wear headphones...   Ta

Answer (score 3):

Using the `My` namespace in VB.NET, you can get access to audio by going through `My.Computer.Audio`. This has a `Play` method with a number of overloads that allow you to pass in a .wav sound by file location or as a Byte array or Stream, but it also has a `PlaySystemSound` method which takes an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds.aspx), one of which is `Beep`. So the full line to play this sound is:

```
My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Beep)
```

No guarantees but as it's part of the .Net framework I think this *should* work on XP and Vista...

Comment: This gives only the warning message "doop" over the sound card, thanks though

Comment: I don't have a copy of Reflector handy, but I'd be willing to bet that function just wraps the Win32 `Beep` function, which, as we've already discussed, doesn't work on 64-bit versions of Windows XP. Also see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: @CodyGray It calls MessageBeep in user32.dll

Comment: Ah, yes. Mapping to the parameter `0xFFFFFFFF`, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356.aspx). That'll do the same thing as `Beep`. The `MessageBeep` function is just an expanded version of that function. Unfortunately, that also confirms that it won't work. :-)

Comment: Just to muddy the waters a little, I built a 64-bit XP Pro virtual machine today to try this on. I expected it to throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException` if `Beep` is unsupported on 64-bit, but it just worked albeit through, as @Toby said, the sound card.

Comment: That shouldn't muddy the waters. That's exactly what it's supposed to do.